# Extract a value from multiple objects inside an array using Regex

Tags: json, regex

I need to find a regex expression which extracts values from objects inside a json array. (It is used in the [AuthKEY WebService Body Response UserGroup Service](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/authkey/index.html) in Geoserver to identify / parse the group values)

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "some": "info",
    "date": 12345689541231,
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": "sjfdewldnnasdjoafe",
            "title": "Core Team"
        },      
        {
            "id": "kasdmeklsoemklsiem",
            "title": "Group A"
        },      
        {
            "id": "adfeeddseerwerwefe",
            "title": "Group B"
        }
    ]
}
```

The result should look like this. Quotes should be removed as well.

```
Core Team, Group A, Group B
```

Is this possible in regex?

Comment: Better to use a json parser

Comment: Unfortunately not an option

Comment: What language are you using that doesn't allow a JSON parser?  Parsing JSON with a regex is highly error-prone and is going to leave you frustrated and sad.

Comment: no language on my side here - it is a tool that excepts a regex to filter data received from an external server which maps the username and groups. See https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/authkey/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how strict is your structure, if you want the escaped strings, you can do this.

```js
// this pattern extracts with the quotes
const pattern = /{\s|[^{}]*"title"\s*:\s*("(?:\\"|.)*")\s|[^{}]*}/gm
input = `{
    "foo": "bar",
    "some": "info",
    "date": 12345689541231,
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": "sjfdewldnnasdjoafe",
            "title": "Core Team"
        },
        {
            "id": "kasdmeklsoemklsiem",
            "title": "Group A"
        },
        {
            "id": "adfeeddseerwerwefe",
            "title": "Group B"
        }
    ]
}`

const escapedTitles = input.split(r).filter((v,i) => i % 2 === 1 && v)
const titles = escapedTitles.map(JSON.parse) // this is unescaping the strings
```

The split function will retrieve the capture of the matches in the even positions, the odd positions brings the text between two consecutive matches that may be helpful for debugging.

If you only want to strip quote marks you simply move the quotes outside the capture group.

```
const pattern2 = /{\s|[^{}]*"title"\s*:\s*"((?:\\"|.)*)"\s|[^{}]*}/gm
const titles2 = input.split(r).filter((v, i) => i % 2 === 1 && v)
```

Having answered your question, what I would recommend is to parse and get the actual data.

```
JSON.parse(input).groups.map(g => g.title)
```

If your concern is speed, the JSON parse is slightly faster in my browser than the other two solutions. https://jsbench.me/2mkky7v8jy/1

Comment: Thank you! Pattern2 did the trick. Unfortunantely parsing is not an option here....